# Find a formula for $T\left(\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix}\right)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $v_1=(1,3), v_2=(-1,4)$, and $A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 3 \\ -2 & 5\end{bmatrix}$ be the matrix for $T:R^2\to R^2$ relative to the basis $B=\{v_1,v_2\}$.

> a.) Find $[T(v_1)]_B$ and $[T(v_2)]_B$.

Since $A$ is the $B$-matrix for $T$, $A=\begin{bmatrix}[T(v_1)]_B &[T(v_2)]_B \end{bmatrix}$.

So $[T(v_1)]_B=(1,-2)$ and $[T(v_2)]_B=(3,5)$.

> b.) Find $T(v_1)$ and $T(v_2)$.

I am not sure about this one, but since $B$ is also the basis for for the codomain and we know that the weights of $T(v_1)$ and $T(v_2)$ as a linear combination of $B$ were given in $(a)$, so we should have
$$T(v_1)=1v_1+(-2)v_2=(3,-5) \text{ and } T(v_2)=3b_1+5b_2=(-2,29) $$

> c.) Find a formula for $T\left(\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix}\right)$.

I don't know how to do this one. I have drawn a diagram that takes $x$ to $[x]_B$ then to $[T(x)]_B$ but I don't know how to go from any of these to $T(x)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(a) and (b) are correct.

For (c), write $x=[x_1\ x_2]^T$ as a linear combination of $v_1 $ and $v_2$. Note that $[x]_B=\left[\frac{x_2+4x_1}{7}\ \frac{x_2-3x_1}{7}\right]^T$. Since $A$ is matrix representation wrt $B$, $[T(x)]_B=A[x]_B$. And you get the actual value of $T(x)$ using a similar technique in (b).

Comment: How did you get the entries of $[x]_B$?

Comment: Solve the system $A\cdot \begin{bmatrix} z_1\\z_2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\ x_2\end{bmatrix}$. Solution $[z_1\ z_2]^T$ is the coordinate vector of $x$ wrt $B$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $(x_1,x_2) \in R^2$. Since $B=\{v_1,v_2\}$ is a basis of $R^2$.

$(x_1,x_2)=a(1,3)+b(-1,4)$, where $a,b$ are scalar. Solve the equation and find $a,b$ . We can see $a=(x_2+4x_1)/7$ and $b=(x_2-3x_1)/7$.
Therefore $(x_1,x_2)=\frac{x_2+4x_1}{7}(1,3)+\frac{x_2-3x_1}{7}(-1,4) $. Now apply $T$, we get $T(x_1,x_2)=T(\frac{x_2+4x_1}{7}(1,3)+\frac{x_2-3x_1}{7}(-1,4))$

$T(x_1,x_2)=\frac{x_2+4x_1}{7} T((1,3))+\frac{x_2-3x_1}{7}T((-1,4))$(since $T$ is linear)

$T(x_1,x_2)=\frac{x_2+4x_1}{7}(1,-2)+\frac{x_2-3x_1}{7}(3,5)$